# What is the difference between these two index declarations and do I need both?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I was examining a script with 'Display Estimated Execution Plan' and it made several recommendations for indexes to add to the database.  I added them and the script did indeed run much faster.  Now I'm looking at putting these into our standard form for inclusion into our regular upgrade scripts and I noticed what might be a redundancy:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TableA_ColA]
ON [dbo].[TableA] ([ColA])
INCLUDE ([ColB])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TableA_ColB_ColA]
ON [dbo].[TableA] ([ColB],[ColA])
GO
```

I can see [from the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) that there are some differences between the two indexes as far as space usage is concerned, but in this case `ColA` is `int` and `ColB` is `nvarchar(255)`, well under the 900 byte limit, so I'm not sure that the `INCLUDE` in the first index is necessary.

So is this just an arbitrary result of the execution plan analyser?  It seems to me if I have the second index the first one is redundant?

Comment: Regarding "do I need both?" impossible for us to tell you as it requires an evaluation of costs and benefits to your overall workload.

Comment: @MartinSmith What I meant by 'do I need both' was 'are these two index declarations essentially equivalent', but apparently not :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They satisfy different queries.

The first one will be useful for queries that seek on `ColA = X` and return `ColB` (without the `INCLUDE` this would require a lookup back to the base table)

The second one will be useful for queries that seek on `ColB = Y`

Both of them can be used for queries like `ColA = X AND ColB = Y` but the second one will do this more efficiently as the first index would require a seek on `ColA` then the residual predicate be evaluated against all matching index rows.

Comment: As a follow up to this question, what is the advantage of putting the column in the include section rather than in the index itself?

Comment: @MatthewSteeples It is only stored on the leaf pages then. Not the upper level pages.